# Como usar un funcion en Jquery

Tags: jquery

Aqui tomen en cuenta que solo ejecutare el Else; donde quiero que luego de aplicar el estilo css me gustaria llamar a otra funcion

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.boton').click(function(){
   if ( $('.relat')=="block") {
    
   }else{
    
    $(".relat").css({"display":"block",},function(){
     alert("fsdss22222");
    })

    // .animate({"margin-top":"50px","display":"none"});

   }
  });
 });
```

```css
.boton{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: slateblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 .relat{
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background: tan;
     color: red;
     display: none;
 }
 .animado{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: brown;
     color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boton">Click aqui</div>
<div class="relat">relat
 <div class="animado">animado</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Además a lo expuesto por @Alvaro  que no es posible realizar una función luego de llamar a la función `CSS` de Jquery dado que se ejecuta de forma síncrona

> quiero que luego de aplicar el estilo css me gustaria llamar a otra
>   funcion

Para simular esto , Se podría usar el [setTimeout(funcion,tiempo)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) ya que si no le damos el retardo parecerá que se ejecuta antes la función que el cambio en el `CSS`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.boton').click(function(){
  if ( $('.relat')=="block") {

  }else{
   $(".relat").css({"display":"block",})
   setTimeout(function(){
     alert("se modificó el display");
   }, 1000);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.boton{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: slateblue;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;}
.relat{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: tan;
 color: red;
 display: none;}
.animado{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: brown;
 color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boton">Click aqui</div>
<div class="relat">relat
 <div class="animado">animado</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás llamando "mal" al método [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) de jQuery: no tiene ninguna opción para ejecutar una función en cuanto termine. En parte, porque realmente  no lo necesita: se ejecuta de manera síncrona, por lo que incluso si admitiera una función a ejecutarse después del cambio CSS, no habría diferencia entre poner el código en dicha función o directamente después de `.css()`.

La solución es sencilla: quita la función y pon el código justo detrás del `.css`. Así, en lugar de hacer:

```
$(".relat").css({"display":"block"}, function(){
    alert("fsdss22222");
})
```

que no funciona, lo que deberías hacer es:

```
$(".relat").css({"display":"block"});
alert("fsdss22222");
```

que sí funcionará. Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
function miFuncion() {
  alert("123456");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.boton').click(function(){
    if ( $('.relat')=="block") {
    
    }else{
    
      $(".relat").css({"display":"block"})
      miFuncion();

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.boton{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: slateblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 .relat{
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background: tan;
     color: red;
     display: none;
 }
 .animado{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: brown;
     color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boton">Click aqui</div>
<div class="relat">relat
  <div class="animado">animado</div>
</div>
```

---

Y si lo que quieres es que sea una función anónima en lugar de una definida en tu código, simplemente crea una función y llámala automáticamente. La idea es la misma:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.boton').click(function(){
    if ( $('.relat')=="block") {
    
    }else{
    
      $(".relat").css({"display":"block"});
      
      // aquí puedes definir tu función anónima y llamarla
      (function() {
        alert("123456");
      })();

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.boton{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: slateblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 .relat{
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background: tan;
     color: red;
     display: none;
 }
 .animado{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: brown;
     color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boton">Click aqui</div>
<div class="relat">relat
  <div class="animado">animado</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no amigo, eso no es lo que quiero yo necesito que se ejecute despues del css una funcion, el alert simplemente es una guia para cuando entre en la funcion

Comment: @Gamez lo que quieres es que se ejecute una función después del CSS. Ponla después del `.css()` como te digo en la respuesta. He actualizado el ejemplo de la respuesta para que se vea más claro

Comment: perfecto amigo ese si hace las funciones pero ahora tengo una incognita que pasa si no quiero usar .css si no; animate ??, lo intente remplasandolo y no me funciona solo ejecuta el alert pero el estilo no lo hace

Comment: Eso es porque `display` no es animable (_animatable_ en inglés). En la [documentación de jQuery para `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) se menciona que funciona con propiedades con valores numéricos y que no funcionará con la mayoría de los valores no numéricos. En lugar de usar  `animate()` podrías usar [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) que cambiará el `display` a `block` y te permitirá ejecutar una función cuando se complete el efecto.

Comment: interesante gracias amigo